# Box mounting point

Tags: junction-box, transformer, relay

What are the chances of this setup passing an inspection? 4x4 box is mounted on a stud, relay attached to the bottom 1/2 knockout, transformer will be mounted at the front of the box. This is in garage, so I plan to cover the hole with a removable plastic panel.

[image]

Comment: Will the junction box cover be accessible without tools?  If you grab the bottom of the relay and yank to the left, will it go flubba-flubba?

Comment: yes, the box will be accessible without tools. Relay has screw holes, I'll probably bolt it to the stud as well, although even now it barely moves

Comment: I wouldn't bother, the very fact that it's flush to the junction box should hold it. The rule is  "without disassembling any part of  the building" so when I say "without tools" I include the same screwdriver you'd use to take the junction box cover off.  I live in Victorian houses where they'd finish this as an adorable little cabinet with a latch.  And when you need access, boom, there it is.  Super easy to change my tub/shower spigot, *why doesn't everybody do this?*

Comment: I take it the 24VAC/class2 wiring is running off somewhere else to a low-voltage thingy before it heads to the relay coil?

Comment: yes, this is correct, running into a whole in the bottom stud

Comment: Is that the firewall between the house and the garage? If it is there that is more of a problem than the electrical.